# How do I access my iPhone 4's UDID?

Tags: udid

I have just bought an iPhone 4 for development.

Unfortunately, I forgot to register my phone to my development account before I tried installing the iOS 4.3 beta 2 software.

Now I can't restore my iPhone because I haven't got my UDID in my developer account, and I cannot get the UDID in iTunes because my phone is stuck in recovery mode.

Does anyone know how to restore my phone, or how to get the UDID into the developer account so it can be restored?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just click "Restore" in recovery mode in iTunes and it'll restore the current 4.2.1 firmware.

Perhaps you need to put it in [DFU mode](http://www.iclarified.com/entry/index.php?enid=1034) first.

Comment: Make sure the screen is completely black, otherwise it's not in DFU mode and probably won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this online service — http://get.udid.io
You should open the site on your mobile, tap the button and follow instructions, I've been described in my blog. It's easy as taping "Next" every time. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you downgrade the firmware by downloading the older version from the internet and hold shift and click restore and select the firmware file?

Comment: http://www.iphoneheat.com/2010/11/download-ios-4-2-firmware-for-ipad-iphone-ipod-touch/  -Firmware download